Where does $x\mapsto e^{-x}-(1-\frac xn)^n$ reach its maximum?
For all integer $n\ge2$, the map $f_n:[0,n]\to\mathbb{R},x\mapsto e^{-x}-(1-\frac xn)^n$ reaches its maximum at some $x_n$. I could prove that $1<x_n<2$.
I would like to show that the sequence $(x_n)$ is an increasing one and that $\lim_{n\to+\infty}x_n=2$.

What have you tried? Where did this question come from?

The points $x_n$ satisfy $f_n'(x_n)=0$ by a theorem of Fermat, so we'll compute them explicitly.
First, differentiate:
$$f_n'(x)=-e^{-x}+\left( 1-\frac{x}{n} \right)^{n-1}.$$
Now equate to zero and isolate $x$:
$$e^{-x}=\left( 1-\frac{x}{n} \right)^{n-1}.$$
This seems so be hard to simplify, but fortunately there's a way to do it using the Lambert W function which is multivalued and has branches, but since we're dealing with real numbers we only need to deal with two branches: $W_{-1}$ and $W_0$, in case you've never seen them before they solve:
$$ye^y=x \iff y=W_k(x) \quad k=-1,\,0.$$
This is solvable in the reals only for $y \geq -e^{-1}$.
Since $0\leq x \leq n$, we have that $1-\frac{x}{n}\geq 0$, so critical points satisfy the following by taking roots
$$\exp\left(-\frac{x}{n-1}\right)=\frac{n-x}{n}\iff (x-n)\exp\left(\frac{x}{n-1}\right)=-n.$$
Now we transform it so that we can use $W$.
$$\frac{x-n}{n-1}\exp\left(\frac{x-n}{n-1}\right)=-\frac{n}{n-1}\exp\left(\frac{-n}{n-1}\right).$$
Now
$$\frac{x-n}{n-1}=W_k\left(-\frac{n}{n-1}\exp\left(\frac{-n}{n-1}\right)\right).$$
And this gives us an explicit expression for the $x_n$ up to branch:
$$x_n = (n-1)W_k\left(-\frac{n}{n-1}\exp\left(\frac{-n}{n-1}\right)\right) + n.$$
To find which branch is useful, let $m=-\frac{n}{n-1}<-1$, so that
$$x_n=(n-1)W_k(me^m)+n.$$
From the definition of $W_k$ we can conclude that
$$W_0(me^m)=m,\quad m \geq -1;\qquad W_{-1}(me^m)=m,\quad m \leq -1.$$
So for $k=-1$ we obtain
$$x_n=(n-1)\cdot m + n = 0.$$
And we don't care about this solution since you proved that $1<x_n<2$.
So, finally, a closed expression for $x_n$ is
$$x_n=(n-1)W_0(me^m)+n.$$
To prove that this sequence is increasing, consider it as a continuous function of $n$ and compute its derivative. Note that $-e^{-1}<me^m<0$, meaning that $-1<W_0(me^m)<0$.
$$\frac{dx_n}{dn}=W_0(me^m)+(n-1)W_0'(me^m)+1.$$
The derivative of $W$ is given by:
$$W'(x)=\frac{1}{x+e^{W(x)}}.$$
Then
$$\frac{dx_n}{dn}=1+W_0(me^m)-\frac{1}{(n-1)^2}\left(\frac{e^m}{me^m+e^{W_0(me^m)}}\right).$$
You should try to prove that this is positive, as such the sequence of maxima is increasing.
To notice that this tends to 2 when $n\to\infty$ you can compute a Laurent expansion of $W_0$ to get the desired result.
Edit:
Since the question was closed, I'll leave you to compute the details for yourself, you can check out more details on $W$ on here and on MathWorld, but the resulting Laurent series expansion should be
$$x_n=2-\frac{2}{3n}-\frac{2}{9n^2}-\frac{14}{135n^3}-\frac{22}{405n^4}+O\left(n^{-5}\right).$$
As such:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=2.$$
